# updating this static page controller code to a newer rails version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I've been trying to use the code here:

http://snafu.diarrhea.ch/blog/article/4-serving-static-content-with-rails

but I'm getting errors like:

```
 undefined method `template_exists?' for #<StaticController:0xb74cbe4c>
```

How can I update this method to Rails 2.5? Probably there are other deprecated things too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call **template_exists?** is deprecated as of Rails 2.2.1 (see:  [Rails APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/template_exists%3F))

A little bit of digging revealed the solution, by the original author, in the following article [article](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=28135).  Basically requires adding the method into the StaticController, derived from ApplicationController and thus gives the method.